# Angular 2 Material Customize md-menu

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I am new to Angular 2 Material and I am trying to customize the style of the md-menu component.

```
<md-icon class="material-icons" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">dehaze</md-icon>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
  <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</md-menu>
```

The predefined style settings work fine (e.g. setting the Menu to non-overlapping), but I would like to set the md-menu to 100% width and have a little space between the md-icon button, that expands the menu, which I can not do with the [predefined directives from Angular 2 Material](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api).

So far I found a solution with the /deep/ css command, but I read that the command is not supported by the major browsers any more.

What is a good way to customize a Angular 2 Material component? How could I style my md-menu, so that it has 100% width and some space between it´s expanding button?

To illustrate what I am talking about:
[Draft of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zldUS.png)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass custom classes to menus.

```
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" class="my-full-width-menu">
```

Then you can target that class with global styles.

For your needs, unfortunately, you'll need to know some information about where your menu overlay is positioned, and hardcode some repositioning

```
.mat-menu-panel.my-full-width-menu {
  max-width: none;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5AmjaFwwAiIZO6CX7mgr?p=preview)

The *right* way to do this is to create a custom overlay component with material's OverlayModule (current in the material package, but soon to be moved to the cdk).

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked for me. I have still two questions: why do you know that you need to use ".mat-menu-panel"? I didn´t see that name in the Angular Material docs. And is it somehow possible to define that class in the app.component.css instead of the global styles.css? I tried it out, but it just seems to work, when the code part is in the global styles.css.

Comment: I figured out to use `.mat-menu-panel` by inspecting the DOM after opening the menu. I wasn't sure exactly where the class would be added, so I had to go in and find it. It's important to use at least 2 selectors in order to be more specific that the original .mat-menu-panel styles. Also sure, you can define those styles in your app.component.css, but you must set ViewEncapsulation to None in your component. This is because the menu-panel is a direct child of the md-menu component, not your app component!

Answer (score 6):

In Angular, ViewEncapsulation.Emulated is the default option which means, it tries to narrow-down the scope of the affect by adding surrogate keys to the host-element etc. One option could be is to add below css. But mind, this ng-deep will also be deprecated soon. Have to wait to know the alternative! https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

```
::ng-deep .mat-menu-panel {
  max-width: none!important;
  min-width: 400px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To style mat-menu without turning off encapsulation for this component you should use 2 classes to increase specificity as exactly as you already did or use !important. However, to make it work you should put them into your **global stylesheet** so that you will override the default styles.