# How to make md-select 100% width?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I use last version angular. This is material design code:

```
<md-grid-tile>
 <md-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
 </md-select>
</md-grid-tile>
```

I try to set `width: 100%`for `md-select. But it does not work.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45356181/5556177)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your problem.

```
<md-grid-tile>
    <md-select placeholder="Favorite food" 
               [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" 
               name="food"
               [style.width]="'100%'">
    </md-select>
</md-grid-tile>
```

Comment: It does not work. I have empty/blank padding around select list

Comment: well it does, see tile 4, 8 and 9 in this plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/rGahhd9yy62sQbDJpbED?p=preview

Comment: Yes, set please background and alsi I need height 100%. After margin: 5px;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150964/discussion-between-faisal-and-daniel).

Comment: Okay, then how to set margin?

Comment: Put the md-select inside a span. See tile 9 in the updated code on plunker and accept the answer if it helped you. Closing this discussion here.