# How to create mega menu on Angular material 7

Tags: angular, angular-material, mdbootstrap

I have used the below code to create the toolbar and menu using angular material 7. I have a requirement to create a mega menu in angular material.

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="example-toolbar">
    <mat-toolbar-row style="height: 28px !important;">
            <div class="div-center">
                <button mat-flat-button color="primary" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
                    <mat-icon>directions_car</mat-icon>
                    Cars
                </button>
                <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
                    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
                </mat-menu>
            </div>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

I am looking for a mega menu createing like this https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/navigation/mega-menu/

Can anyone know how can I create the mega menu like above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak the **`mat-menu`** component a bit and build your own component to make a mega menu component.

Otherwise there is no direct way to configure with the material.

[`SIMPLE DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-topnav-menu-1mwddt?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-topnav-menu-1mwddt?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: This one I know.

Answer (score 0):

[Angular 2 Material Customize md-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354098/angular-2-material-customize-md-menu)

```
.mat-menu-panel .custom {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10322